# Moving average of values stored in an InfluxDB database

Tags: influxdb

I'm looking to create a moving average over 1 year, 1 month and 1 day of the value which is stored in a InfluxDB. I came across [this functionality](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#moving-average).
However, the values I have are not recorded in fixed time intervals. So while the function works on the example

```
name: h2o_feet
time                   water_level
----                   -----------
2015-08-18T00:00:00Z   2.064
2015-08-18T00:06:00Z   2.116
2015-08-18T00:12:00Z   2.028
2015-08-18T00:18:00Z   2.126
2015-08-18T00:24:00Z   2.041
2015-08-18T00:30:00Z   2.051
```

It wouldn't work on mine (I believe), which would look like this:

```
name: h2o_feet
time                   water_level
----                   -----------
2015-08-18T00:00:00Z   2.064
2015-08-18T00:01:00Z   2.116
2015-08-18T00:12:00Z   2.028
2015-08-18T00:12:30Z   2.126
2015-08-18T00:14:00Z   2.041
2015-08-18T00:30:00Z   2.051
```

Is there a way to do this using influxdb functions?

Comment: Your two sets of data appear identical to me.  What is the question?

Comment: check the timestamps